# Turn columns to rows in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with the names of newborn babies per year.

```
"name","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013"
"Aicha",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0
"Aida",15,20,16,0,10,0,10,14,13,11,12,11,13,14,13,18
"Aina",0,0,0,0,0,0,16,12,15,13,12,14,10,11,0,12
"Aisha",14,0,10,12,15,13,28,33,26,26,52,44,43,54,68,80
"Ajla",15,10,0,0,22,18,28,27,26,26,19,16,19,22,17,27
"Alba",0,0,14,14,22,14,17,19,23,15,28,32,25,33,33,33
```

I want to plot this in a line chart, where each line is a different name and the x axis is the years. In order to do that, I imagine I need to reshape the data into something like this:

```
"name","year","value"
"Aicha","1998",0
"Aicha","1999",0
"Aicha","2000",0
...
```

How do I reshape the data in that fashion? I've tried `pivot_table` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars="name", var_name="year")
>>> df_melted.head()
    name  year  value
0  Aicha  1998      0
1   Aida  1998     15
2   Aina  1998      0
3  Aisha  1998     14
4   Ajla  1998     15
```

and then sort using

```
>>> df_melted = df_melted.sort("name")
```

if you liked.